# Logging Authenticated users on apache/php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So I know to use 
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']

Which will show the current username of the the authenticated user.

BUT instead, I want to be able to dump a list of all the the currently live users who are authenticated (and their IP address etc)
Can this be done in php? or even bash will be good too, running apache with php 5

Comment: You need to define what "currently live" means in this context? The server, in and of itself only knows when users are actively making requests, not when they are viewing a page (or have closed the page in the browser altogether). If you can define what live means to you (i.e. users with requests in last X seconds or whatever) you can get better advice on possible strategies.

Comment: Well The logged in users are making requests every 2 seconds on my system automatically. But I was wondering if there was an easy solution to dump all live sessions of the users. For example; when you log in it will ask you for your user/pass. now if you close the tab and open it again your session will still be alive and wont ask you again for the the user/pass, its these live sessions I was referring to, (or any other way?)

Comment: They are not live sessions. The browser requests a page, and then the connection is closed* and the user gone - unless he eventually requests another page. The usual approach is to store all single users that had requested a page in a central place and count anyone that requested a page within the last X minutes as still online. )* I know about HTTP1.1